# Some of the Coq Standard Library cannot be loaded

Tags: coq

I recently installed coq on my system (first from the arch user repository, but then via opam, facing the same problem). When I wanted to try out the standard Library, I realized that some libraries can be loaded while others can not. For example

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Logic.
```

works out just fine, whereas

```
Require Import Lists.
```

or

```
Require Import Sets.
```

results in the message

```
Unable to locate library Lists.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: It's singular: `List`, not `Lists`.

Comment: If this solves your problem, then I'd appreciate if you deleted the question. It feels like a question more suitable for a chat: IRC on freenode, #coq channel or [functionalprogramming.slack.com](https://functionalprogramming.slack.com) (#coq). I think you would get an answer in seconds :)

Comment: Seconded, that is a good point.